# Batch Script to find Folder Length of 2 alpha-numerics only and delete thos folders

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

I need a batch script that will search in one folder or root, Not recursively, for folders with a folder name that has only two letters or numbers. Example   A1   B0  E2  22  52 . I had a program that would dump folders on the C drive and i now i have hundreds of folders on many computers. I want to delete these folders. I do not have any folders as short as 2 letters that are needed.  Can someone help?

Comment: what do you mean with `alphanumerics` .  are file names like `~~`  alphanumeric ?

Comment: a-z 0-9     only folder names. or any combination  A1   1A  B0 0B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will delete all empty folders with two characters *or less*:

for /f %%i in ('dir /b /ad ??') do rd %%i

If you want also not-empty folders to be deleted:

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /ad ??') do rd %%i /s /q
```

If you use it not within a batchfile but as a single command, replace every `%%i` with `%i`

EDIT (exclude  a folder):

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /ad ??') do ( if "%%i" neq "FP" rd %%i /s /q )
```

Comment: this looks like it should work,  can you exclude one folder name. example   FP   ???

Answer (score 3):

this removes only folders with two letters or digits in its name:

```
for %%i in ('dir /b /ad ?? ^| findstr /r "^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]$"') do echo rd /s /q "%%~i"
```

Look at the output and remove the word `echo` if it looks good. For a more advenced use of Regex have a look at [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm).

Comment: is this supposed to work on stock windows? do i need to install any supporting files?

Comment: I tried using this across a few computers and i could not get it working. I used it in a bat file and ran at c:    (C:  \)

Comment: Yes, if you don't remove the `echo`  command, this doesn't work.

Comment: i got that, i will do some more testing as this is alittle more exact.